# eclipse compiling error

Tags: c++, cygwin

I just installed cygwin and eclipse on my win7 x64 machine, and after importing my code from svn, I get this weird error:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project platform ****

make all 
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0   -c -o platform.o platform.cpp
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe, g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -c -o     platform.o platform.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=5): Access is denied.

make: *** [platform.o] Error 5
```

I've tried running eclipse as administrator, but that doesn't make any difference. Any clue how to fix this?

My windows PATH variable is `C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin;C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\;C:\cygwin\bin`

Comment: just wondering, is `C:\cygwin\bin\` in windows' PATH variable?

Comment: Yes, my PATH variable includes C:\cygwin\bin

Comment: Can you try using g++.exe to compile a simple Hello World program? Does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe is a Cygwin symbolic link pointing to either g++-3.exe or g++-4.exe. Native Windows functions such as CreateProcess() don't understand Cygwin symbolic links though. Hence you need to configure Eclipse to execute g++-3.exe or g++-4.exe directly.